# ASP.NET how to assign to CalendarExtender attribute SelectedDate = CalendarTextBox.Text

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, usability

ASP.NET with AjaxContolToolkit.

I have a `CalendarExtender` inside editable `GridView` control.

I want to do a simple thing: assing an existring date value of `TextBox.Text` or `Label.Text` to the `SelectedDate` attribute to make editing more user-friendly. The task is pretty simple, isn't it?!

```
...
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="accdateLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("totalaccdate") %>'></asp:Label> 
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="accdateEditTxtBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("totalaccdate") %>' ReadOnly="True" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="accdateEditTxtBoxCalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="accdateEditTxtBox" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" PopupButtonID="accdateEditCalImage" 
StartDate="01-01-2011" EndDate='<%# DateTime.Now %>' SelectedDate='???'/>
<asp:Image ID="accdateEditCalImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar.gif" />
</EditItemTemplate>
...
```

I've tried many snippets, nothing helped!

And, please, could it be done **without** additional JavaScript.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to do it when you bind your datagrid??

Comment: No, `CalendarExtender` appears on `Image` click to edit `TextBox` in edit-mode. `TextBox.Text` has the same value as `Label` in read-mode and the value needs to be passed to the `SelectDate` attribute on this row. Only one row at a time is editable. You know, this is quite usual, nothing special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify the `SelectedDate` because it is the date that is already in the TextBox. So you can set the `TextBox.Text` property and it will be taken as the `SelectedDate` automatically.

But you need to to use **the same format** as the `CalendarExtender` uses.

In your case (for example in the GridView's `RowDataBound` event):

```
accdateEditTxtBox.Text = theDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Thank you! It really works. I just changed the SQL query output format.